# How do i connect PHP files to HTML?

Tags: php, html, mysql

**Quick Note**

I'm on a fair beginner's level of web development HTML, CSS, javascript ran locally.
For this, I'm using *Visual Studio Code*.

**To The Problem**

Recently I've gotten to the part where I need web server functions and database control.
For this, I decided to go with *XAMPP & MySQL Community Server*. There have been no issues with setting this up locally.

So when I started delving into PHP coding, it's fun and I've already created a couple of files and also managed to make the PHP files connect to my database.

**HOWEVER** I can't seem to find one obvious way to actually connect my *".php" files* to my actual main document which is the HTML document.

I might have misunderstood how PHP actually works, though to make an example to my question;

Just like you have your HTML document separated from a CSS document, at least in VS Code, you establish a connection link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" for **example**, for my reasons at least to make the workspace much cleaner than bombarding the HTML document with CSS.

How do I do this with PHP files? Cause whenever I run my PHP files as they are, they work as intended, but I can't find a way to actually bind/connect them to my HTML document.

I'd love some input or a proper answer to this, and I will gladly respond with the necessary information.

Cheers :)!

Comment: So there are a couple of ways you can do this.. It sounds like you're on a beginners path, so without touching on things like JS xhr requests to get data, you can actually `echo` html content in your php file iteself.. `echo("<h1>Hello</h1>")`..

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php

Comment: .php *replaces* your .html, basically. You access your .php file, and it *outputs* HTML as a result. Basically, rename your .html file to .php, and replace some parts of it with dynamic `<?php ... ?>` code. — Now, the more complex your app gets, the more you want to separate your PHP code into several files, and the HTML into a separate template, which you put together using `require`/`include` statements.

Comment: @Pogrindis for larger parts of static HTML, https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php would probably be the better place to link to.

Comment: deceze is right. It's worth noting as well though that more complex design approaches may attempt to introduce a separation between HTML and PHP again. e.g. in an MVC framework most of the PHP "logic" is in the controllers and models, and the display code is in views, which are essentially like templates - they consist mostly of static HTML but have some PHP or PHP-like code in them to control exactly what gets displayed, they can make use of any data passed to them by the controller...

Comment: ...or you may get a design like a lot of modern apps where there's total separation of client and server-side - e.g. the PHP acts more like an API where you just send and receive structured data (e.g. in JSON format) from it rather than exchanging HTML and form data. And then the front-end might be built using a Javascript framework like React or Vue or Angular, and it just send AJAX requests to the PHP whenever it needs to save or load data. (This architecture is common when you may have multiple front-ends or clients, e.g. web app, mobile app, desktop app, IoT device all talking to the PHP)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will use html inside the php file. So instead of having an `index.html`, you will have an `index.php` file where you place all your html in there `doctype`, `head`, etc. And then inside the html you inject php code with `<?php echo 'foo'; ?>`

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <title></title>
  <base href="">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<h1>Some html text</h1>
<?php echo 'This is php code'; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so so so much for this answer! It's funny how easy the solution was and also how you and all the others who commented with your input, increased my basic understanding for PHP. 
BIG THANKS :)! @deceze

Answer (score 0):

HTML and Javascript is Client side and PHP is Server side.

That mean you have 2 possibilities:

1. Send data from your HTML Site to your .php
2. Receive Data from your .php in your HTML

For Begginers:

To send data to your .php use `<form>` Tag
This allows you to send Data to your .php file

Example:

HTML Site:

```
<form action="yourphpfile.php" action='post'>

Firstname <input type=text id=firstname name=name> 

Lastname <input type=text id=lastname name=lastname> 

<button type=submit> Go! </button>

</form>
```

Your .php file

```
<?php

$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname= $_POST['lastname'];

echo("<p>Welcome " . $firstname . " " . $lastname . " </p");
```